# Is clickable is possible inside scrollview?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

In my application i want to load more then one view inside scrollview and also give more no.of imageview inside each and every view...if give so,is it clickable is possible...

give me a solution to do this...

Thank You,

Varshu

Comment: What have you tried so far? (because that should just work without any special code)

Comment: hi...i want to give more then one view inside scrollview whereas each and every view has more then one imageview...i want all the imageview must be clickable...is it possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [PhotoScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html) sample application. This application demonstrates the use of embedded UIScrollViews and CATiledLayer to create a rich user experience for displaying and paginating photos that can be individually panned and zoomed. CATiledLayer is used to increase the performance of paging, panning, and zooming with high-resolution images or large sets of photos.